# fingGetting this error from swift mailer Address in mailbox given [ ] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Although I've seen most of the answers online for this kind of error, mine just seems different.
Building a simple contact form using swiftmailer,
My ContactsController,

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Contacts;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\MyMail;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function contact(Request $request) {

        // dd($request->file('resume'));

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required', 
            'company' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'company' => $request->company,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'message' => $request->message
        );
        
        
        Mail::to(config('mail.support.address'))->send(new MyMail($data));
     

        $contacts = new Contacts;
        $contacts->name = $request->input('name');
        $contacts->email = $request->input('email');
        $contacts->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $contacts->company = $request->input('company');
        $contacts->subject = $request->input('subject');
        $contacts->message = $request->input('message');
        $contacts-> save();
        return redirect('/contact-us')->with('response', 'Message Sent Successfully');

    }
}
```

MyMail.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
       $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
        ->to(config('mail.from.address'))
        ->subject(' Mail')
        ->from('myaddress@gmail.com')
        ->view('emails.contact_message');
    }
}
```

my config/mail.php

```html
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'myaddress@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Do not Reply'],
'encryption' =>  env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

I don't where the error is coming from and I've been trying to debug it for some days, I followed the exact steps of a tutorial online and nothing like this happened in the tutorial

Comment: @lucidlogic isnt it set correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the to address `config('mail.support.address')` can't be empty

Comment: I'm currently confused. could you write out an example

Comment: sure in `ContactsController` change `Mail::to(config('mail.support.address'))->send(new MyMail($data));` to `Mail::to(config('mail.from.address'))->send(new MyMail($data));`